# Synaptic asks for root password but doesn't open in 17.10

Tags: synaptic

It asks for root password, but nothing happens. I noticed the software works only with proprietary drivers (Nvidia) enabled, but I want the open-source ones (nouveau x org) since I'm tired of entering my root password every time I boot. Help please!

Comment: @pomsky I don't have gksudo

Comment: The problem is the same, read the linked post carefully, it comes all down to Wayland preventing some applications to run.

Comment: No, at the moment I don't have nVidia drivers enabled! I just noticed this strange (to me) thing in a  previous installation of 17.10

Comment: @pomsky Excuse me, but I don't understand which, of the linked methods, is better for me. I just need to use **Synaptic** (since GNOME Software doesn't work well with single packages), not others root/GUI programs.

Comment: Are you running or intending to run standard Ubuntu or one of the community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu)? Only standard Ubuntu 17.10 runs Wayland, and you can switch to Xorg, where you can run Synaptic without any tweaks. You can also make it work with Wayland with the 'xhost tweak' described at the 'possible duplicate' link. - At first you can try manually, and if you wish, you can make things more convenient later on (according to one of the answers at the 'possible duplicate' link.)

Comment: Standard Ubuntu (Ubuntu *tout court*) 17.10. Thank you, @sudodus!

Comment: 1. You switch between Wayland and Xorg at the log in screen. Click on the cog wheel and select which graphical system you want. (Ubuntu will remember what you selected, so you need not click on the cog wheel every time, only when you want to change the selection.) ; 2. You can use `sudo -H synaptic` instead of `gksudo synaptic`